# javascript read file and put content as variable

Tags: javascript, variables, readfile

I am a beginner at javascript, so please before saying duplicate or anything, please try to help me by pointing me in the right direction to where I should seek the answers.
I see many questions like this but none relative to my need.
So, i have to ask..

I have a javascript, with

```
this.a.$a = "content";
```

Now somewhere in that script, I have

```
a.target_url = this.a.$a;
```

That *this.a.$a* was a string that we manually added via input box.

What i need is a function to read a file contents, convert it into a string, and print the value as a variable in `this.a.$a`.

The file name is Test.txt, with long URI as http://www.mydomain.com/test.txt

The file contents is : *Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet*

I have tried

```
$.get("http://www.mydomain.com/test.txt", function(data) { 
    this.a.$a = data
});
```

But what I got was `[object] [Object]`.

Can someone explain this to me please?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You should try outputing the variable with console.log, then check firebug to see what the object looks like. Though my gut tells me this should fix your problem:

```
$.get("http://www.mydomain.com/test.txt", function(data) { 
    this.a.$a = data.d
});
```

Comment: thank you.
will trying to see thru firebug, mean while i will added the .d